# Rails 6: Ajax not accepting render in js.erb

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am trying to display the results of a SHOW action using AJAX.

in the show.js.erb, this renders properly:

```
$('#someid').html("<p>regular html</p>")
```

and this renders the name of the selected @category

```
$('#someid').html("<%= j render @categories %>")
```

but does not work when trying to render the associated SHOW view (show.html.erb):

```
$('#someid').html("<%= j render 'show', category: @category %>")
```

the errors i recieve is as follows:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Missing partial categories/_show with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:js, :html, :text, :css, :ics, :csv, :vcf, :vtt, :png, :jpeg, :gif, :bmp, :tiff, :svg, :mpeg, :mp3, :ogg, :m4a, :webm, :mp4, :otf, :ttf, :woff, :woff2, :xml, :rss, :atom, :yaml, :multipart_form, :url_encoded_form, :json, :pdf, :zip, :gzip], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
  * "/home/ubuntu/environment/project_name/app/views"
  * "/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/actiontext-6.0.3/app/views"
  * "/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/actionmailbox-6.0.3/app/views"
):
    1: $('#someid').html("<%= j render 'show', category: @category %>")
  
app/views/categories/show.js.erb:1
```

what can I do to render show.html.erb?

Comment: What errors do you have?

Comment: i updated my question with the broswer console error i recieve

Comment: Look at the response on Network tab. It think there full error trace

Comment: GET 500 error means that your Rails server returned a 500 - Internal Server Error. Check the logs or the terminal where you are running the server. Please add the stack trace and the other code relevant  to the question. My guess is that something in your show view raised an uncaught exception.

Comment: Yes, i was looking at the wrong errors, and looking at the correct ones helped me solve the problem. thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

you should change folder `show.html.erb` -> `_show.html.erb`
because it is templale partial to render

Answer (score 0):

Answer on the behalf of OP:

> The issue, in the end, was that the `show.html.erb` needed to be named
> `_show.html.erb`
>
> I was looking at the browser errors and not the rails server errors. I
> posted the errors still, to document my solving process.
>
> I was able to see that in this line in the error
>
> ```
> ActionView::Template::Error (Missing partial categories/_show with {:locale=>[:en], .......
> ```
>
> Had the underscore before `show.html.erb`, something not immediately
> apparent to me upon using AJAX for the first time.